# Preview doesn't show the content of text file with a certain extension (`.jl`) in Finder

Tags: finder, preview, python, text

When looking for a script of a programm (`.py` for Python, `.m` for Matlab, `.jl` Julia or `.txt` in general) it is very handy to go in the finder a simply highlight that script file ==> then a preview of that script appears on the right side in Finder. However, for the Julia script file `.jl` there is no such preview ==> nothin appear on the right side although it is a normal text file, the proof is that when I change the extension to `.txt`, the preview is available. How do I do to have that preview available